# How to search for a perfect match in xCode 4?

Tags: xcode4

Is there a way in xCode4 to search for all variables with a specific name and not just trying to match part of the name over all code ?

I need perfect match, for example, I have a variable called "myVar", and when I search for it, I don't want results with longer names including "myVar", such as "myVar2" or "allmyVars".

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is a way. Just bring up the advanced options on search navigator (click on the magnifying glass > *Show Find Options*) and choose *match search term*

[image]